# How to enter a specific node in xpath with Python and lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Imagine the Following HTML

```
<div class="group>
    <ul class="smallList">
        <li><strong>Date</strong>
            some Date
       </li>
       <li>
            <strong>Author</strong>
            some Name
       </li>
       <li>
            <strong>Keywords</strong>
            <a href="linka"
            rel="nofollow">keyworda</a>,
            <a href="linkb"
             rel="nofollow">Keywordb</a>,
       </li>
       <li>
            <strong>Print</strong>
            <a class="icon print" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:window.print()">print page</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="group>
    <ul class="smallList">
        <li><a href="linkc">Linktext</a></li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

I am looking for keyworda and keywordb. So only the words within the lsistelement that contains  Keywords

I can get all the nodes by using

```
.//div[@class='group']/ul[@class='smallList']/li/a/node()
```

but how do I enter just the specific one?

Comment: Looks like you almost had it with your xpath; you just need to add a predicate to `li`... `.//div[@class='group']/ul[@class='smallList']/li[strong='Keywords']/a/node()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to get the Keyword entries, using Xpath. The [contains](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XPath/CSS_Equivalents#Contains_Equivalent) function can help here. I'll use the [parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) library, simply because it is easy to use IMO. This can be replicated with lxml or some other library in Python as well.

```
data = "[your html above here]"
from parsel import Selector
sel = Selector(data)

#the path looks for the hyperlink and checks for two conditions:
#1. href contains link AND
#2. rel contains nofollow. 
#after that access the text for this path
path = ".//a[contains(@href,'link') and contains(@rel,'nofollow')]/text()"

#extract text using getall() :
print(sel.xpath(path).getall())

['keyworda', 'Keywordb']
```